# how can I copy a usb stick data to a virtual space in my server

Tags: virtualization

I got a software that requires a usb stick to be plugged in my server in order to run. How can I copy the content and putted into my server, so i never need to use the usb again?

I was thinking first how to get the data since is not accessible trough explore option and no file visible (even with show  hidden files carpet option activated).

And then creating a sort of permanent partition if required or just copy the data into a carpet in my server.

I thought of create a virtual usb into my server to emulate a physical USB.

OS: Windows SERVER 2003 R2.

Thank you for the  answers.

Answer (score 1):

What is on the "USB Stick?" Many times this is a hardware key to allow a certain application to run, this is different from a USB flash drive. A USB key is usually in combination with a product key/serial number to ensure that the person that has installed the application is the same person that is authorized to use it (ie it is not pirated). If this is the case, you'll need the key.

Comment: For reference, this is called a "dongle": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongle

Comment: It's actually called a lot of things, one of which being dongle. In dealing with vendors you almost never hear the term "dongle." It even says as much in the link provided.

Comment: Ok, but I want to not have to use  the product key/serial number is there a legal way I can just get this so I don't have to use the key?

Comment: That's between your organization and the software vendor, but as a general rule, no. If they have a hardware key for software you have to use it, otherwise they wouldn't have it.